# Amazon S3 upload responds with HTTP 403: Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

This is going to be a long post, but since I have no idea where things are going wrong, I figure it's better to be overly verbose than leave out essential information.

I am attempting to upload images to my Amazon S3 bucket as per this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python.

I set up my code as follows:

**index.html**

```
<img id="preview" src="https://via.placeholder.com/320?text=Image+Upload">
<input id="file_input" class="form-control" type="file" name="image" accept="image/*">
<form method="POST" action="/gallery/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="lVE...ASG">
    <input type="hidden" id="image-url" name="image-url">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price">
    <div class="form-control">
        <input type="checkbox" name="archive" value="True">
        <label for="archive">Archive</label>
    </div>
    <input class="form-control btn-primary" type="submit">
</form>
```

**s3.js**

```
function uploadFile(file, s3Data, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", s3Data.url);

    var postData = new FormData();
    for (key in s3Data.fields) {
        postData.append(key, s3Data.fields[key]);
    }
    postData.append('file', file);
    for (var [key, value] of postData.entries()) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 204) {
                document.getElementById("preview").src = url;
                document.getElementById("image-url").value = url;
            }
            else {
                alert("Could not upload file.");
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(postData);
}

function getSignedRequest(file) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "/gallery/sign_s3?file_name="
                    + file.name + "&file_type=" + file.type);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                uploadFile(file, response.data, response.url);
            }
            else {
                alert("Could not get signed URL.");
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    (function () {
        document.getElementById("file_input").onchange = function () {
            var files = document.getElementById("file_input").files;
            var file = files[0];
            if (!file) {
                return alert("No file selected.");
            }
            getSignedRequest(file);
        };
    })();
});
```

**views.py**

```
S3_BUCKET = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
)

def sign_s3(request):
    file_name = request.GET.get('file_name')
    file_type = request.GET.get('file_type')

    presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
        Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        Key=file_name,
        Fields={"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
        Conditions=[
            {"acl": "public-read"},
            {"Content-Type": file_type}
        ],
        ExpiresIn=3600
    )

    return JsonResponse({
        'data': presigned_post,
        'url': 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (S3_BUCKET, file_name)
    })
```

When I select an image with the file uploader, I get an alert saying "Could not upload file," along with the following output from the Chrome developer console:

```
acl: public-read
Content-Type: image/jpeg
key: dragon.jpg
x-amz-algorithm: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
x-amz-credential: AKI...TRA/20190224/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request
x-amz-date: 20190224T044659Z
policy: eyJ...XX0=
x-amz-signature: 7ea...18a
file: [object File]
```

It appears that the pre-signing goes through, but I get this XML as a response from the upload:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>5D1...AB5</RequestId>
  <HostId>cYX...WKw=</HostId>
</Error>
```

My CORS policy is very lenient (I plan on changing this later, but for now, I want to prevent access from being restricted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I tried editing the Bucket Policy, but I still get an "Access Denied" error. This guide was of little use: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-denied-bucket-policy/

I don't know what is causing this, but my guess is that there's a permissions issue somewhere. I don't know where. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** User's policies are `AdministratorAccess` and `AmazonS3FullAccess`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Edit 2:** I was able to make changes to my bucket policy by unchecking "Block new public bucket policies" in Public Access Settings. Setting it to the following no longer resulted in an "Access Denied" error message on the Bucket Policy page, but I am still unable to upload the file via XHR:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy...237",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt...935",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::coolwater-creations/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "...764"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: When you try to edit the bucket policy I'm assuming you're doing it via the console and not the cli?
If so, did you check your IAM permissions? Do they include s3 policies?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it from the console. There is one user and it has only the `AdministratorAccess` policy applied. I've now attached the `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy, but I still receive an Access Denied error both from the XHR and from editing the bucket policy.

Comment: Can you copy the policies this user has to the question? That's mainly where the error is.
Also double check that you're logged in with that user, if you have administrator access you should be able to modify s3.

If you share some screenshots of your console that'd help too.

Comment: I added them to the question. Specifically, what console screenshots would you like?

Comment: Can you add in the whole policy? i.e.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "service-prefix:action-name",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "DateGreaterThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": "2017-07-01T00:00:00Z"},
            "DateLessThan": {"aws:CurrentTime": "2017-12-31T23:59:59Z"}
        }
    }
}
```

If you add in a screenshot of the IAM console area (hide any sensitive details but leave the usernames in there) and of the s3 error that might help

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eqsZ1MN

Comment: Screenshots are unreadable, but the likely explanation is that your bucket is configured with multiple options not to allow public access, which could prevent you from uploading a file with `public-read` and could also prevent you from setting a policy that is too lax.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/

Comment: Hi Matt, were you able to solve this issue in the meanwhile? I am struggling with the exact same thing, but am unable to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, @Alex, I haven't worked on this issue for a couple years, and have no immediate plans to return to this service.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is you're logged in with a different account than the one you see in IAM:

From the screenshots you shared notice how in your screenshot the name of the IAM user doesn't match your username

[image]

If you're logged in as that IAM user, you should see that same name in your username

[image]

So you're either logged in as the root account at which case the error will be in how the bucket got created (check https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/)
Or you're using an SSO of an AWS partner to login at which case your permissions in there are a bit different and not controlled by the IAM you see there.

Comment: I believe I am logged in as the root account in the console, but I don't know what account I'm logged in as with the SDK. I used my `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` to login. I also have them in my  `.aws/config` file, but I think that is used for the CLI.

Comment: What do I do from here? The link you provided wasn't helpful, unfortunately.

Comment: how wasn't it helpful? Did you go through the troubleshooting steps?

Comment: I did. The canonical IDs match, I don't have any conflicting deny statements in my bucket policy, I've verified the user credentials that I'm using to access S3, I'm not using an EC2 instance, the object is not missing because I'm attempting to POST, not GET, I'm not worried about KMS encryption, Requester Pays is not enabled, and I am not using AWS Organizations.